# Synapse Lake database view not available in SQL Pool?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, delta-lake

Currently exploring using Spark notebooks in Synapse for data transformation instead of data flows but the lake db capabilities are a little confusing.

I created a lake db, an external table (catalog?) and a view using a notebook in Synapse Workspace. The view is visible in the Synapse UI and I can query it.
But the view is not available when connecting via the SQL pool using management or data studio for example. Are only table meta data shared, or am I missing something? Having trouble finding documentation regarding this.

Comment: We have many Lake DBs and they are all accessible in SSMS, so you should definitely see them there. The workspace UI does not have the ability to show the View code, but you can still access this through SSMS.

Comment: I can see the DBs and tables just fine in SSMS, but not the views that was created using Spark. Same using Azure Data Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have SQL Views, not views in our Lake DBs (those are all tables).

Comment: We use Temp Views in our notebooks - can you show a sample of the notebook code you are using to create the Views in the Lake DB?

Comment: %%sql

CREATE VIEW the_db.my_view AS
SELECT * FROM the_db.my_table

Comment: I think, only table meta data is shared with the SQL Pool unfortunately, not the views

Comment: We've used this approach to create Temporary Views before, but never tried to persist them. Can you query that View from other Notebooks?

Comment: Sure, they work fine using notebooks

Comment: I think @aravind-yarram has the correct answer. If you need to access these assets via SQL, you'll need to persist them as Tables. Another option would be to create a serverless SQL database and create Views there that reads the LakeDB parquet files using OPENROWSET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**But the view is not available when connecting via the SQL pool using management or data studio for example. Is this intended, or am I missing something?**

- The Serverless SQL Pool and the Spark Pool share a catalog, but the **Dedicated SQL Pool has its own**.
- Spark views are session (temp views) or app (global views) scoped and do not belong in the catalog. That is the reason you don't see views.

Comment: I am not using the Dedicated SQL Pool

Comment: @Fiffe Updated my answer based on your comment. Somehow, I inferred you were asking about tables (not views).